# Clean and precompile rails assets manually on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline

My issue is that there are a lot of changes which I did in the app/assets folder so in my development environment I easily undid the old ones with this command.

```
rake assets:clobber
```

and then recompiled with this one.

```
rake assets:precompile --trace
```

It all works well on my local. Now the issue is that few changes have messed up on heroku.  Although heroku precompiles assets while pushing the code on it, I want to precompile the assets manually. When going through the generated application.css it has specified values four times rather than once. First and third time the value is right but the second and fourth is wrong so it is picking up that wrong one I guess. So I want to fix it up by cleaning the assets and precompiling it afresh. Thanx for the help.

Comment: `heroku run bundle exec rake assets:clobber` and `heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: No changes. Clobber shows removed     Removed /app/public/assets but precompile does nth. Running command shows and nth seems to compile as it actually looks when we precompile on dvelopment or production anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> precompile the assets manually

Heroku's [ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) is rebuilt each time you push your code. Thus, in theory (Heroku often has its own way of doing things), your assets will be wiped with each new deploy.

---

[It's a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27190778/1143732), but you can invoke rake tasks off the back of `assets:clean`:

```
# lib/tasks/heroku_migrate.rb
Rake::Task['assets:clean'].enhance do
  Rake::Task['assets:clobber'].invoke
  ...
end
```

--

In regards to your asset pipeline, if you're getting a particular issue with the way your stylesheets are compiled, it suggests you have an issue with the underlying code/implementation.

Perhaps showing what issue you're getting with that would be beneficial?

-

You can, of course, precompile locally with a simulated `production` environment:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

---

**Update**

We use the following:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.5' #-> Icons

#app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass
@import font-awesome
```

You don't need any more than that if you're using `font-awesome`.

Of course, if you're looking to use variables or mixins (we HIGHLY recommend [`bourbon`](http://bourbon.io/)), you can use them as you please. You just don't need to add `font-awesome` files to your pipeline if you're using the gem.

Comment: Basically there are few variables in defined and used in a scss file. They are repitive four times on heroku. And it is picking the empty one like this:      fa-play-circle-o:before{content:""}}. The content is nil. It should pick up the variable. Local is ruuning fine while heroku has issues.

Comment: So it's an issue with `font-awesome`?

Comment: Yes! U got me once again @Rich

Comment: We use `font-awesome` successfuly on Heroku - which version of the gem are you using?

Comment: gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.5.0'

Comment: Okay let me put up our code; I doubt it's much different but it may give you some steps to get thing sorted. FA should work on Heroku

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100367/discussion-between-techdreams-and-rich-peck).